# Read multiple excels according to the date and year you have

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How can I read multiple xlsx files in order and place them in the same dataframe?

Right now I have the following code which is giving me `Error: No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\HN_1701.xlsx'`

```
months=['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']

years=['21','20','19','18','17']

years=list(reversed(years))

for i in years:
    for j in months:
        
        
        print(r'C:\HN_'+j+i+'.xlsx')
        xls = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\HN_'+j+i+'.xlsx', sheet_name="ER", header=9)
```

Comment: How are the files named, what is the pattern, if any?

Comment: file name : HN_022021 ... 022017 month and year

Comment: If your file names are mmyyyy then you want to add the `20` to the years and switch the order since it is currently looking for yymm format.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Here, I do this for csv-files but it works the same with xlxs files. I look at a private folder but you can translate this to your own. First, define all the years, months and days you need. Create an empty df.

```
import pandas as pd
months=['04']
day = ['13','14','21']
years=['2021']

df = []
for years in years:
    for months in months:
        for day in day:
            path = r"C:\Users\k_sego\repos\wagon_report_weekly\Data_by_day\\" 
            filename = "{}all_vehicle_day_agg_{}-{}-{}.csv".format(path, years, months,day)
            print(filename)
            df.append(pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";"))
```

which returns:

```
C:\Users\k_sego\repos\wagon_report_weekly\Data_by_day\\all_vehicle_day_agg_2021-04-13.csv
C:\Users\k_sego\repos\wagon_report_weekly\Data_by_day\\all_vehicle_day_agg_2021-04-14.csv
C:\Users\k_sego\repos\wagon_report_weekly\Data_by_day\\all_vehicle_day_agg_2021-04-21.csv
```

and your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the regex way to get the list of all files that match like this:

```
import os
import re
file_list = [file for file in os.listdir('test/') if re.search(r'HN_(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12).{2}(21|20|19|18|17)+\.xlsx$', file)]
for file in file_list:
    xls = pd.read_excel(f'C:\Users\{file}', sheet_name="ER", header=9)
```

Play with the regex and see what works best for you.